# using CASE WHEN in SQL Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have to display information by comparing data in two ID columns, one column has 'ALL' and numbers as ID's while the other has only numbers in it as  ID's. My problem is, I cannot compare character and number columns with a number column. So I am using CASE WHEN.

If the value is 'ALL' then display 'ALL' in the output, else display name for the matching records.

Here is the code:

```
CASE
  WHEN secorg.org_id = 'ALL' THEN 'ALL'
  WHEN secorg.org_id = progmap.org_id THEN secorg.org_name
END AS org_name,
```

the condition is this: 'secorg.org_id = progmap.org_id' which is based on the id and I have to display secorg.org_name if the id's are same.

Here is the entire query:

```
SELECT distinct program_id,
                prog_name,
                case
                  when Eitc_Active_Switch = '1' then 'ON'
                  when Eitc_Active_Switch = '0'then 'OFF'
                End as Prog_Status,
                progmap.client_id,
                case
                  when secorg.org_id = 'ALL' then 'ALL'
                  --when secorg.org_id = progmap.org_id then secorg.org_name
                  else secorg.org_name
                end as org_name,
                case
                  when prog.has_post_calc_screen = 'True' then 'True'
                  Else 'False'
                End as Referal_ID,
                case
                  when progmap.program_ID IN ( 'AMC1931', 'AMCABD', 'AMCMNMI',
                                               'AMC' )
                       And sec.calwinexists_ind = '1' then 'Yes'
                  when progmap.program_ID IN ( 'AMC1931', 'AMCABD', 'AMCMNMI',
                                               'AMC' )
                       And sec.calwinexists_ind = '0'then 'No'
                  when progmap.program_ID NOT IN (
                       'AMC1931', 'AMCABD', 'AMCMNMI', 'AMC' ) then
                  'N/A'
                End as calwin_interface,
                sec.Client_name
FROM   ref_programs prog (nolock)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN ref_county_program_map progmap (nolock)
         ON progmap.program_id = prog.prog_id
            AND progmap.CLIENT_ID = prog.CLIENT_ID
       INNER join sec_clients sec (nolock)
         on sec.client_id = progmap.Client_id
       Inner join sec_organization secorg (nolock)
         on secorg.org_id = progmap.org_id
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: It'd help to know what database you're using

Comment: I get the error at 'ALL', it says that: "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'ALL' to data type int"

Answer (score 1):

Why not cast the number columns to varchar columns?

If you're using SQL SERVER you can do that like so:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR,secorg.org_id) = CONVERT(VARCHAR,progmap.org_id)
```

You'll have to do an outer join for instances when the column that is both 'ALL' and numbers is 'All' as it won't be able to inner join to the other table.

For the quick fix based on your code above you can just change the second WHEN clause to look like so (again assuming you're using MS SQL SERVER):

```
WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,secorg.org_id) = CONVERT(VARCHAR,progmap.org_id) THEN secorg.org_name
```

Try this as your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    program_id, 
    prog_name,
    CASE Eitc_Active_Switch
        WHEN '1' THEN 'ON'
        ELSE 'OFF'
    END AS Prog_Status,
    progmap.client_id,
    ISNULL(secorg.org_name,'ALL') AS org_name,
    CASE prog.has_post_calc_screen
        WHEN 'True' THEN 'True'
        ELSE 'False'
    END AS Referal_ID,
    CASE WHEN progmap.program_ID IN ('AMC1931','AMCABD','AMCMNMI','AMC') AND sec.calwinexists_ind = '1' THEN
        'Yes'
        WHEN progmap.program_ID IN ('AMC1931','AMCABD','AMCMNMI','AMC') AND sec.calwinexists_ind = '0' THEN
        'No'
        WHEN progmap.program_ID NOT IN ('AMC1931','AMCABD','AMCMNMI','AMC') THEN
        'N/A'
    END AS calwin_interface,
    sec.Client_name
FROM
    ref_programs prog (nolock)
LEFT OUTER JOIN ref_county_program_map progmap (nolock) ON progmap.program_id = prog.prog_id AND progmap.CLIENT_ID = prog.CLIENT_ID
INNER JOIN sec_clients sec (nolock) ON sec.client_id = progmap.Client_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sec_organization secorg (nolock) ON CONVERT(VARCHAR,secorg.org_id) = CONVERT(VARCHAR,progmap.org_id)
```

Comment: I have posted my entire query. Please take a look at it

Comment: The data in the number and 'ALL' column is collected based on some condition. I cannot alter it. I only have to display name for matching id's in both the columns.

Comment: yes i am using sql server. it is stored procedure i am writing

Comment: I did like you said. but it gives me error saying   Incorrect syntax near '.'

Comment: It gives me this error message? "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'ALL' to data type int"

Comment: how can i get the datatype names of the entire table

Comment: Actually I see the problem... you can eliminate the case statement for the org_name all together from the query if you are using that last inner join in your query... I've edited it once more, give it a go.

Comment: I have to search them based on their id's....Other wise the entire query is wrong!

Comment: I used your query...I only get output with numeric values I cannot display the 'ALL' values at all

Comment: If you're doing the last inner join you have in your query then that case statement you had is moot because only one of the columns you said have the value 'all' so there fore the inner join will eliminate all the records that have 'all' in the one column since they don't exist in the other. The last inner join insures that the two tables join and will always have a valid org_name returned.

Comment: If you want the all values as well the last join you have needs to be an outer join and I'll have to add the case statement back in for the org_name...

Comment: I understand that. But the requirement is that It should display records only if they have a matching id otherwise it should display the 'ALL' optioin

Comment: Ok. I can run the query without error and will all the matching values...but its a large number of records in the result sent..than what i previouly used to get...previously i use to get 440 recoreds with a combination of ALL and number ...now i am getting 20000 records...

Comment: I dont think this is suppose to happen!!

Comment: keep your query as you have it then but make these 2 changes... on line 11 of your query change it to read END AS org_name and on the very last line of you query make it read like this... Inner join sec_organization secorg (nolock)
         on CONVERT(VARCHAR,secorg.org_id) = CONVERT(VARCHAR,progmap.org_id)

Answer (score 1):

The case statement is fine its the field alias thats bad it shoud be

```
     END As org_name
```

A multipart alias like secorg.org_name won't work